# re.split() works in the interpreter, but, fails on script execution. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, split, python-re

I am having a strange issue.  I am trying to write a script to automate NFS mounts and it seems that it is failing on a re.split.  I would like to use any number of spaces to delimit the strings, but, for some reason when I run the script it fails.  I am generate the following error when I run my script.

```
     basilius@HomeComing:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1$ sudo python3 mount_py3.py lin 
     file.txt rw,noac,suid
     Enter the name of the default group:  basilius
     Enter the default group name:  basilius
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "mount_py3.py", line 146, in <module>
        main()
     File "mount_py3.py", line 125, in main
       export, mount_point = re.split(' +', line)
    ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

for the following code.

```
        inp_file = open(args.filein, 'r')
        for line in inp_file.readline():
            export, mount_point = re.split(' +', line)
```

I use argparse to pass the name of the script, as a string, to the script.  It is not being opened by argparse.

When I directly invoke the interpreter it works fine.  See below.

```
basilius@HomeComing:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> inp_file = open('file.txt', 'r')
>>> line = inp_file.readline()
>>> print(line)
server:/opt/website    /srv/program

>>> export, mount_point = re.split(' +', line)
>>> print(export, mount_point)
server:/opt/website /srv/program

>>>
```

When I do just a straght readlines() on the file it returns everything in the correct format.

It is a straght text file for the export and mount_point for fstab entry. I am not sure why I am getting different results.  Could someone assit?  I have been pounding the internet for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your loop, where you write `for line in inp_file.readline():`. This reads a single line from the file, and loops over the characters in the string, assigning each one to `line` in turn.

You probably want `for line in inp_file:`, which loops over the lines in the file one at a time. You could also call `readlines()` (with an "s" on the end) on the file, which does the same thing but uses more memory.

Or, I suppose, if you only care about the first line of the file, you could just do `line = inp_file.readline()` without the `for` loop.

Unrelated to your issue, it's a probably good idea to use a `with` statement to handle the opening and closing of your file: `with open(args.filein, 'r') as inp_file:`, followed by the rest of the code that uses it indented by one level.